# Get direction of jQuery Resizable Action

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

I've got a simple jQuery resizable element:

```
element.resizable({
    start: function(event, ui) {
        if(draggingDown()) {...};
    };
});
```

I want do something if the user is about to drag down. In the `start` callback, how can you find out if the user is dragging up or down?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
var h = element.height();
element.resizable({
    resize: function(event, ui) {
        if($(this).height() > h) {...};
        h = $(this).height();
    };
});
```